# What limit should I set for Oracle character types, when there is no business constraint?

Tags: oracle, data-modeling, oracle19c

I'm used to designing for PostgreSQL, whose character types don't have performance differences, and where the community's advice is that an explicit limit only exists to enforce a business rule.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html

Now I am working in Oracle (19c). My choices for character types seem to be either VARCHAR2 with a mandatory limit, or CLOB.

The community advice seems to be to avoid CLOB wherever possible. It's not clear to me whether this is for performance reasons, reasons of tradition, or because CLOBs do not display in query editors without some manipulation.

If there is no rule from the business, or domain, that suggests a maximum length for a text field, what technical, performance, or user experience factors should I consider when choosing a limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*whether this is for performance reasons*" - that. CLOBs are extremely slow in Oracle (especially if you change them a lot)

If there is no business rule and 4000 bytes(!) seem to be enough for the time being, go with `varchar2(4000)`.

Don't be tempted to use extended varchars that allow `varchar2(32767)` - they are stored as CLOBs in the background and suffer the same performance problems.

Comment: Also, if you are using a multi-byte character set like AL32UTF8, then consider specifying the number of characters in your VARCHAR2 field instead of bytes. Otherwise you may find that you don't get a consistent number of characters in the field when double-byte characters are used. e.g. "varchar2(100 char)".

Comment: @pmdba: but note that this still does not overcome the 4000 bytes limit!

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: *Avoid CLOBs, use VARCHAR2 with a reasonable length.*

I agree completely with @a_horse_with_no_name regarding CLOBs and `varchar2(32767)`.

However, I would not recommend to the the maximum size for `VARCHAR2(4000)`, but to use a sensible upper limit, which is actually quite difficult to estimate. Users and other developers will hate you if the field is too short. And the database will do strange things if the field is too long.

Because `VARCHAR2` stores only the actual used characters, you won't find any difference on the storage side, it's performance during insert, update or delete is very likely identical.

However, sometimes Oracle assumes the maximum length is actually used:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  a VARCHAR2(   1 CHAR),
  b VARCHAR2(   1 CHAR),
  c VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR),
  d VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)
);

CREATE INDEX i1 ON t(a,b);
Index I1 created.

CREATE INDEX i1000 ON t(c, d);
ORA-01450: maximum key length (6398) exceeded
```

Furthermore, there is sometimes an performance impact when the database server (or client application) allocates memory by the maximum length, for example:

```
INSERT INTO t SELECT 'a','a','a','a' FROM all_objects;
INSERT INTO t SELECT 'b','b','b','b' FROM all_objects;
INSERT INTO t SELECT 'c','c','c','c' FROM all_objects;
INSERT INTO t SELECT 'd','d','d','d' FROM all_objects;
EXECUTE dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(null, 't');
SET AUTOTRACE TRACEONLY STAT
```

Now sorting by the `VARCHAR2(1)` columns happens in memory (which is fast):

```
SELECT a,b FROM t ORDER BY a,b;

Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
      1  sorts (memory)
      0  sorts (disk)
 268520  rows processed
```

while sorting by the `VARCHAR2(4000)` columns doesn't fit in memory and has therefore to be sorted on disk, which is slow:

```
SELECT c,d FROM t ORDER BY c,d;

Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
      0  sorts (memory)
      1  sorts (disk)
 268520  rows processed
```

I have to admit that I set the available memory to a very small amount just to prove the point, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for an excellent answer! I suppose Oracle's reputation for best performance comes from giving users who know what they're doing the possibility of squeezing every last bit out of the system. Manual transmission. I also suppose that I'm resisting the usual strategy for low-knowledge data modelling situations: make your best educated guess. This helps me understand the trade-offs better.